# Regular expression to match social security number

Tags: php

what can be the regular expression for social security number in php?

=====================================================================

For what reason below given this can be used?

```
([0123][0-9])-([01][0-9])-([0-9]{4})
```

Comment: *(related)* [How can I validate US Social Security Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517026/how-can-i-validate-us-social-security-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
'#\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\b#'
```

Comment: Is ([0123][0-9])-([01][0-9])-([0-9]{4}) it serve same purpose as '#\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\b#'?

Comment: @Poonam: Nope, they are different, you can read the basics of regex to clarify things up :)

Comment: Nit picking here but the following are valid 9 digit socials which are not actually valid: 666584848, 000565959, 123001564, 123450000, 987-65-4320, 987-65-4321. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number#Valid_SSNs)

Answer (score 2):

PCRE - Exact:

```
\b(?!000)(?!666)(?:[0-6]\d{2}|7(?:[0-356]\d|7[012]))[- ](?!00)\d{2}[- ](?!0000)\d{4}\b
```

PCRE - Quick:

```
\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\b
```

Both from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
^\(?[0-9]{3} [^0-9]{0,2}([0-9]{2}) [^0-9]?([0-9]{4})?$
```