# Regular Expression in php

Tags: php

For what below given expression can be used to match?

```
([0123][0-9])-([01][0-9])-([0-9]{4})
```

To add on this, It can be social security number, email, date time etc

Comment: Try it out on this site  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reguler expression to match social security number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591171/reguler-expression-to-match-social-security-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can match `00-00-0000` the regex given

Just break the expression down:

```
([0123]    -- Match 0 .. 3
[0-9])     -- Match 0 .. 9
-          -- Match a dash
([01]      -- Match a 0 or a 1
[0-9])     -- Match 0 .. 9
-          -- Match dash
([0-9]{4}) -- Match 4 numbers in the range of 0 .. 9
```

As for the round brackets they just capture the expressions within, ie.  `([0123][0-9])` will capture the first two match pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I've mentioned before how awesome [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) is:

```
([0123][0-9])-([01][0-9])-([0-9]{4})

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([0123][0-9])»
   Match a single character present in the list “0123” «[0123]»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([01][0-9])»
   Match a single character present in the list “01” «[01]»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]»
Match the character “-” literally «-»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «([0-9]{4})»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{4}»
      Exactly 4 times «{4}»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Comment: Commercial ad removed ;P free alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: @mario - Really? Removing a link to a valuable developer tool? By that mentality, we should remove all links to Visual Studio and point to Mono Develop as an alternative. :)

Comment: Hmm, people will still be able to google it. Nevermind, I also thought about pirating it, lol, because unlike "The Regulator" it runs under Linux/Wine. But nevertheless, since we have a nice reference page I thought that's more interesting for casual readers.