# Create variable to flag invalid social security numbers

Tags: r, algorithm, validation

Has anyone created a variable to flag invalid social security numbers? My dataset includes a host of different formats as well as valid and invalid and I am looking for a script that might be able to discern the good from the bad including any with all zeros in any of the three positions as well as ruling out dummy SSN (e.g. 999999999, 078051120, etc.). Thank you in advance!

```
 SSN <- data.frame(SSN = c("123456789", "MR1234567", "666786543", 
"800445678", "45678AB90", "772123456", 
"987654321", "234-56-7890", "123004567", "000345678"))
```

Comment: A previous algorithmic question and good source of information for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517026/how-can-i-validate-us-social-security-number

Comment: @Vincent, I did see this question although I'm not sure how to apply or insert regex into r. Can you recommend a place to go for that?

Comment: can you specify what makes a SSN value valid for non-US users?

Comment: Start with something simple and extend out: `grepl(pattern = "^(\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}|XXX-XX-XXXX)$", SSN$SSN)`

Comment: @Borderlands54 Oh! There are lots of great R regex tutorials online. A quick google finds [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html). You can probably use the same or very similar patterns given in the previous question. Think about a flow-chart of steps to check validity and then try coding one part at a time. You might want to consider things like the character length, replacing'-' with nothing (i.e. ''), flagging non digit characters (i.e. letters, whitespace, symbols) etc. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you both @Vincent and @JasonAizkalns! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@JasonAizkalns has the right idea w.r.t. building out. Here's how I'd do it. This handles all the examples you provided, but it might give you some ideas on how to handle other cases as well.

You'll need to stage it, because trying to make a single regular expression do the job is too tedious and error prone. Because you want to have indexes to the ones that are bad in the original data, you retain those at each step.

1. regularize by removing hyphens. You can extend this to include other punctuation marks, if necessary.

   `SSN$SSN <- gsub('-','', SSN$SSN)`

   If you were to find some other bad character (such as `#`), just add it with a `|` for OR

   `SSN$SSN <- gsub('-|#','', SSN$SSN)`
2. get indexes where entries do *not* have 9 digits; hence, the use of `invert=T`

   `not.9 <- grep('\\d{9}', SSN$SSN, invert=T)`
3. find the three locations where sequential zeros are a no-no; use bars for OR and `^` and `$` to anchor the first and last sets (nnn and nnnn) in each entry

   `zeros <- grep('(^000)|(\\d{3}00)|(0000$)', SSN$SSN)`
4. combine the sets

   `bad.ones <- c(not.9, zeros)`

`print(SSN$SSN[bad.ones])`

[1] "MR1234567" "45678AB90" "123004567" "000345678"

Comment: this is very helpful, thanks! I am using this in an ifelse statement: `SSN$SSN <- ifelse(grepl('\\d{9}', SSN$SSN), SSN$SSN, SSN$new_id)` in order to have those <9 equal to `SSN$new_id` but it is instead returning the index. Any thoughts on how I can have it return the value in a corresponding variable (e.g. SSN$new_id)? Thanks!

Comment: Your method worked for me. I pre-populated the `SSN$new_id` with the correct values [`SSN$new_id <- c('', '121234567', '', '', '456783290','','','','123724567','428345678')`], ran the exact statement you indicated, and `SSN$SSN` had the new values afterward.