# Conditional validation in a JavaScript web form

Tags: javascript, forms, web

I am working on a web form using JavaScript for validation.  This is only one section of a much larger form.

The form has a question that asks the user if they have a Social Security Number. (SocialSecurity field)  It has two radio buttons, one yes and one no.  IF the user answers yes, then another field (SSN) becomes visible.  Otherwise, it stays hidden.   This part is actually working. (the show/hide of the SSN field)

The JS needs to do two things.  IF the user answers yes, then the SSN field becomes required, and must validate that it has 9 integers.   BUT, if the user answers no, then SSN field, which will stay hidden must no longer be required.

What I am having difficulty with, is getting the SSN to be required only if the user answers yes, and validate it correctly under that circumstance.

[Online Demo](http://%20%20https://jsfiddle.net/Ladybug333/acrd4w0n/11/#&togetherjs=KBFMVaj2wS)

**Here is the code:**

```
<div class="field SocialSecurity">
<span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_lb" class="EditingFormLabel">Do you have a Social Security Number?</span> 
<div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpsocialsecurity" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">
<span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list" class="radio radio-list-vertical">
<input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" value="As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number." />
<label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0">As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.</label><br />
<input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" value="Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number." />
<label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1">Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.</label>
</span>

</div></div>

<div class="field SSN">
<label id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_lb" class="EditingFormLabel" for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText">Social Security Number</label> 
<div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpssn" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">
<input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SSN$txtText" type="text" maxlength="9" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText" class="form-control" />
</div> </div>

$('.field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]').on("change", function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.':
      $('.field.SSN').show();
      $('.field.SSN input').focus();
      break;

    case 'Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.':
      $('.field.SSN').hide();
      break;
  }
});


//Here is the SS format validation section

function validateSSN() {
  if (!validateRequiredTextField('SSN', 'Social Security Number'))
    return false;

  var value = $('.field.SSN input').val();

  if (!isInteger(value) ||
    (value.length != 9) ||
    (value == '000000000') ||
    (value == '111111111') ||
    (value == '222222222') ||
    (value == '333333333') ||
    (value == '444444444') ||
    (value == '555555555') ||
    (value == '666666666') ||
    (value == '777777777') ||
    (value == '888888888') ||
    (value == '999999999') ||
    (value == '123456789')) {
    $('.field.SSN input').focus();
    alert("Invalid: Social Security Number");
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

//overall form validation - section on SSN
function validateForm()

if (!validateSSN())
  return false;
```

Comment: Where is your validation logic?  If you included it in your fiddle and not in your question, then please edit your question to include the logic within.  Links are fine in a question, so long as they are not the only method by which to get the scripts.

Comment: One of the problems of developing with ASP.NET Web forms, is that it generates very long identifiers in the HTML. Inefficient...

Comment: I don't actually see where you're submitting the form and calling the validation. It looks like your validation is just running once when the document is loaded and then never again after that.

Comment: I added the JS.  It is also viewable in the fiddle link

Comment: There are alot of errors in your jsfiddle. https://imgur.com/a/z2vHN1u

Comment: What happens if the user disables JS? They could enter any SSN they like. Consider adding a `pattern=` to the SSN field so that the browser's native validation will pick it up. You should also perform validation on the backend  (ASP.NET?) once your form has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Update your validateform() function as below

```
function validateForm()
{
if($("#p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0").is(':checked'))
{
    if($(".field.SSN input").val().trim() == "")
    {
        alert("You must provide SSN!");
        // Instead of alert, you can also apply some style to textBox e.g. red borders
        return false;
    }
    else if (!validateSSN())
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is way to messy to work with. I've created this demo to show you the basics of how I think you should go about this. **Note that I have simplified your code and changed both field names and classnames for the purpose of this demo.** If you choose to implement a solution such as this you will need to update code to use your own values accordingly. (see second snippet.)

**Solution:**

1. Use the browser's native validation by adding `required` and `pattern` attributes to the fields. A simple Rx pattern=`[0-9]{9}` will take care of your 9 integer validation requirement. **Remember to re-validate server-side after the form has been submitted.**
2. Using JavaScript (/jQuery) listen for changes on the SocialSecurity field then set the SSN field's `disabled` attribute to `true` or `false` to *enable* or *disable* it depending on the chosen SocialSecurity value. If you don't want the disabled SSN field to be visible you can have the JS hide its parent container. Note that so long as the field is given the `disabled` property it won't be validated or submitted regardless of whether its visible or not.

**Woking demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var $ssn = $(".SSN");
  //add and enable and disable custom event:
  $ssn.on("enable", function() {
    $(this).show().find("input").attr("disabled", false);
  }).on("disable", function() {
    $(this).hide().find("input").attr("disabled", true);
  })
  //set initial state to disabled:
  $ssn.trigger("disable");
  //listen for changes and change the $ssn state accordingly
  $("input[name='havessn']").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === 'nope') {
      $(".SSN").trigger("disable");
    } else {
      $(".SSN").trigger("enable");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
input:required:valid {
  border: green solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="field SocialSecurity">
    <span>Do you have a Social Security Number?</span>
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" name="havessn" value="yup" required="required" />As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.</label><br />
      <label><input type="radio" name="havessn" value="nope" required="required" />Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.</label>
    </div>

    <div class="field SSN">
      <label>Social Security Number <input name="ssn" type="text" required="required" length="9" pattern="[0-9]{9}" title="Please provide a 9 digit SSN" />
</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Demo for your specific use-case with unwieldy classnames intact:**

```js
$(function() {
  var $ssn = $(".SSN");
  //add and enable and disable custom event:
  $ssn.on("enable", function() {
    $(this).show().find("input").attr("disabled", false);
  }).on("disable", function() {
    $(this).hide().find("input").attr("disabled", true);
  })
  //set initial state to disabled:
  $ssn.trigger("disable");
  //listen for changes and change the $ssn state accordingly
  $("input[name='p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list']").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === "Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.") {
      $(".SSN").trigger("disable");
    } else {
      $(".SSN").trigger("enable");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
input:required:valid {
  border: green solid 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field SocialSecurity">
<span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_lb" class="EditingFormLabel">Do you have a Social Security Number?</span> 
<div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpsocialsecurity" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">
<span id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list" class="radio radio-list-vertical">
<input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" required="required" value="As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number." />
<label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_0">As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.</label><br />
<input id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1" type="radio" name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SocialSecurity$list" required="required" value="Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number." />
<label for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SocialSecurity_list_1">Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number.</label>
</span>

</div></div>

<div class="field SSN">
<label id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_lb" class="EditingFormLabel" for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText">Social Security Number</label> 
<div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpssn" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">
<input name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$SSN$txtText" type="text" required="required" length="9" pattern="[0-9]{9}" title="Please provide a 9 digit SSN" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_SSN_txtText" class="form-control" />
</div></div>
```

Comment: This works in the snippet you provided, however, the catch is that the SSN secton is part of a form that was created in a CMS, so I can't change the labels.  I am limited to: <div class="field SocialSecurity">$$label:SocialSecurity$$ $$input:SocialSecurity$$$$validation:SocialSecurity$$</div>

<div class="field SSN" style="display: none;">$$label:SSN$$ $$input:SSN$$ $$validation:SSN$$</div>

Comment: @user12327549 you just need to update your selectors in the code then. The best option is to use class names. you can pass more than one class name to a jquery selector. Or you can use parent/child, or html selectors in combination, as in `.field > input`.

Comment: @user12327549 I simplified the markup for the purpose of the demo. Those classnames are unwieldy. If you choose to implement this demo code in your application you should update the JavaScript to use your own classnames, field values, etc. My answer explains what you need to change in order to solve your problem.

Comment: @user12327549 I've added a second snippet that retains your overly complex html.

Comment: What about function that validates the SSN format when it is required?   (see orignial post)

Comment: @user12327549 as stated in my answer, the field is validated by the browser's native validation. Try it in the demo snippet. It won't allow you to submit the form with an invalid SSN. Please note that however you validate on the frontend you should still perform separate validation on the backend (ie server-side)

Comment: @user12327549 I'm not familiar with Social Security Numbers but the `pattern="^d{3}-d{2}-d{4}$"` seems more in keeping with the current spec. Validating SSN should be a question in its own right. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517026/how-can-i-validate-us-social-security-number). If you're not happy with my answer please downvote it with an explanation of the issue.